# How can a user query my mongodb with a search bar?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

What should I do to enable users of my website to type in something to a search bar and have it query my mongodb?  I am using meteor JS so perhaps that will help with an answer. Thanks.

Comment: add the events `onchange onkeypress oninput` to the text input, Then when ever the text changes run a query on the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few good meteor packages out there depending on what kind of functionality you need.  I would suggest checking out meteorhacks:search-source, which will implement instant search for you, and does most of the work behind the scenes.

Check out https://meteorhacks.com/implementing-an-instant-search-solution-with-meteor.html for a good intro tutorial.

Comment: great tip, i appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a 'change' event  handler on your `<input>` element and fire off a jQuery `$.post` request. Consider this:

```
$('#input-box').change(function() {
    var postData = $(this).val();
    $.post('/your/url', postData, function(dataFromMongoDB) {
        // Query MongoDB on the server and return the data
        console.log(dataFromMongoDB);
    });
});
```

Comment: awesome thanks for the answer man